# Log messages to window, game application

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a high speed rendering application and I want to output log messages to a **separate window**.  The application is multithreaded, and all the threads might have something to log at any given time.

I am already using the console for output, and that worked fine!

What I did was:

- Create a logMessage queue
- Whenever a thread has something to say, it locks the queue and inserts its message into the queue
- There is **a "flush" thread** that sleeps until some thread logs something (the act of calling `log()` on any thread wakes up the flush thread) and its job is to flush all log messages to a file and the console.

This worked fine for both the file and console logging: neither seems to care that the thread they are receiving print calls is different from the application's main thread.  However, [any other window you create does care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060686/how-do-i-sendmessage-to-a-window-created-on-another-thread).  So now the flush thread doesn't work when I try to print to a [*separate RichText window*](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/richtext-c-windows-win32-api/) that I've created.

So that's disappointing. Now the only solution it seems is to move the **flush** thread code **to the main thread** (the same one that runs the render loop) which means there's a potentially long delay in displaying a frame (if waiting to lock the log queues so they can be outputted), which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've got what looks like a conflict for your flush thread:

- It's a worker thread, which wants to be able to sleep when there's no work to do - likely using WaitForSingleObject on an event handle
- However, if the thread creates a window, it now needs to behave as a GUI thread - which means it's not allowed to block or wait, and instead must return to a message loop (GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage) when it's done its work.

One approach to solve this apparent conflict is as follows:

- Use the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects: this basically a version of WaitFor... that will wake up if the event is fired, *or* if there's a message that the richedit needs to process - which you then process using GetMessage() etc, and when done, go back to MsgWaitFor... and start again, waiting for either the event or GUI messages. It allows the thread to be both a GUI thread and a worker thread.

Another approach (which is likely more work, and I think the above one is more likely a better fit for your existing code - but mentioning this anyhow) is as follows:

- Instead of having the worker thread go to sleep by using WaitForSingleObject, take advantage of the fact that it's a GUI thread; it effectively ends up sleeping by calling GetMessage(), and will wake if another thread posts a message to it. This would require having a hidden window that the thread owns that you can post the message to. (You may also be able to use PostThreadMessage to avoid having to create a hidden window, but it has some tricky issues where messages can appear to 'get lost' if the thread displays a message box or dialog, so a hidden window is the safest approach.)